# Preparing Slack message in pipeline after build stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy, pipeline, message, slack

In the pipeline on which I work, the 4 successive stages correspond to:

1. building a code package,
2. building a binary package,
3. building an Android application
4. building an iOS application.

Then the request to the server (JSON) is performed, which contains information about the build, including: name, success / abort / failure and possible warnings. I don't know how to get information about build is aborted or failure? I should write the information about the build on Slack without using the Jenkins plugin. I need some tips on how to do this because all my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use post actions for this topic like below. And use slack api to send messages without installing slack plugin. Check https://api.slack.com/messaging/sending.

```
   post { 
        success { 
            script {
                //slack
            }
         }
         failure { 
            script {
                //slack
            } 
         }
    }
```